# Object "Nesting"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I want to use an object in nodejs to store url paths, and reuse a previous entry for example:

```js
let URLS = {
  root: "www.example.com",
  paths: {
    user: root + "/user",
    login: root + "/login"
  } 
}
```

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Define `root` as a var first then JSON.stringify your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access `URLS.root` before the object is created, but you can define a separated variable `root` and use that in multiple places in the `URLS` object:

```js
const root = "www.example.com";

const URLS = {
  root,
  paths: {
    user: root + "/user",
    login: root + "/login"
  } 
}

console.log(URLS)
```

In the example above, the `root` property is defined using a [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) instead of writing the property name and the property value separately (e.g. `{ root: root }`).